# ui-router browser back button changes url even abort transition is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have 2 app states and I am using angular ui-router, below is the pseudo code for my app, every thing works fine if I navigate using ui-sref and several buttons in app.

```
$stateProvider.state('app.page1', {
            url: '/page1',
            templateUrl: 'page1.html',
        }).state('app.page2', {
            url: '/page2',
            templateUrl: 'page2.html',
        });
```

Now I have to enforce a condition that once the user is in page2 view/state, he can't go back to page1

```
$transitions.onBefore({ from: 'app.page2.**' }, (trans) => {
    trans.abort();
});
```

Even this works fine if I click on some buttons which can navigate to page1, but my code blocks/abort that transition.

But when I click on **back button of browser**, the url change to **/app#/page1** though the **state is maintained as page2**, **but just the url changes, which shouldn't.**

How to prevent this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: How can I show url changes in fiddle/plunk?

Comment: just give working code, I will test it locally on my environment.

Comment: just for reference to use browser back button you will have to use **BrowserHistory **

Comment: See this comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3416#issuecomment-316896488 I think it should be considered a bug in ui-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a workaround, you can do $location.path($urlRouter.location); when you abort the transition to have the same url for the state, this even preserves the browser history.